# CompareAttribute validator?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Validation attributes are realy nice. But what if I have to compare one property to another. How can I implement that?

Scott has a great example for Email attribute validator at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx
but it's bind to only one property.

What if I need to compare one date to another (DateFrom, DateTo), so that DateFrom is before DateTo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607832/writing-a-compareto-dataannotation-attribute).

Comment: It sure is an ugly solution, but it's a valid answer, so you get your points :)
I think I'm gonna do the validation "the old way"